# MongoDB for huge amount of data

Tags: mongodb, bigdata

I need to get Weather data from almost 200 German cities.

The point is I need to save the data since the beginning of this year and I should save the data from every single day, including the temperature during the hours of the day (Hourly temperature) and the min and max temperature for the whole day.

I know that is a huge amount of data, and it could be even bigger because it’s not decided yet if we will get the historical weather data from 10 years ago till now. Besides that the number of cities included into this could grow to add cities from other countries.

Is MongoDB a good way to save this data? If not, which method would be better to do it?

Comment: IMO This is not a really big amount of data. Unless your data format cannot be inserted in a table, a relational database might still be your best bet. For instance, MariaDB can store up to 64TB of data in a single table, which is probably much more than your requirement.

Comment: It depends on your use case. What are you planning to do with the data? In terms of data size, I believe you have 365 * 24 measurements per city, with 200 city. That would be about 1.75 million data point per year. I think any database would be more than capable of handling that amount of data comfortably with reasonable hardware requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MongoDB for a weather data. MongoDB is **flexible** and d**ocument-based**, you can store JSON-like binary data points in one place without having to define what “types” of data those are in advance.

MongoDB is a schema-less database and can load a **high volume of data** and it's a **very easy to scale**. It supports **sharding** which is the process of storing the data in different machines when the size of the data grows. This results in the horizontal scaling and more amount of data can be written.

It’s been used by **The Weather Channel** organization, because weather changes quickly. The Weather Channel turned to MongoDB to get information to users quickly. Changes that used to take weeks can now be pushed out in hours. So, MongoDB database would be more than capable of handling that amount of weather data.